# create a calc spreadsheet containing a list of documents

Tags: csv, terminal, libreoffice-calc

I need to create a spreadsheet containing a file list. I have a lot of PDF files, ordered like following example:

```
"Abbagnano, Nicola - Historia de la Pedagogía.pdf"
"Abbagnano, Nicola - Introduccion Al Existencialismo.pdf"
"Abbagnano, Nicola - La Evolucion de la Dialectica.pdf"
"Adorno, Theodor - Educacion Para la Emancipacion.pdf"
"Adorno, Theodor - Escritos Filosoficos Tempranos.pdf"
etc...
```

I want a list looking like this

```
   A        |  B      |   C 
Abbagnano | Nicola  | Historia de la Pedagogía
Abbagnano | Nicola  | Introduccion Al Existencialismo
Abbagnano | Nicola  | La Evolucion de la Dialectica
Adorno    | Theodor | Educacion Para la Emancipacion
Adorno    | Theodor | Escritos Filosoficos Tempranos
```

Comment: What terminal shell is this - bash on linux perhaps, or Windows powershell, or something else?  A [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) command could probably do it.  If you have a regular expression that is not working, then please post it to show that you have put some effort into this.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I'm using bash on linux, and this is the regular expression used, which makes the output posted.
    'ls' | sed -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' > files.csv

Comment: Is that the answer you were looking for?  If so, it is recommended to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To convert the former into the latter where the former is already in a ColumnA in LibreOffice:

Select ColumnA, Data > Text to Columns, check Comma and add `-` to Other for Separated by under Separator Options (others unchecked) and Text delimiter `"`, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then <kbd>OK</kbd> again, select ColumnC and Edit > Find & Replace, Find: `.pdf` (leave Replace: blank), Replace All, <kbd>Close</kbd>. Save As... `Text CSV (.csv)(*.csv)`.